# Restify and vue cors cross domain blocked

Tags: cors, middleware, restify

I have a restify server running my API, and I am defining cors middleware as follow:

```
server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser({
  multiples: true,
  mapParams: false
}));
server.pre(restify.CORS())
server.use(restify.fullResponse())
server.use(
  function crossOrigin(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  return next();
});
```

but I am always getting this error message:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://myroute... (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because restify.CORS() is deprecated at restify new version, at least I see it here:

https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/1151

"The restify CORS plugin will be deprecated in the upcoming 5.x release in favor of https://github.com/TabDigital/restify-cors-middleware"

I changed for this plugin and everything worked again.

Comment: I have used restify-cors-middleware but still facing issues 
like this
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/login' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-credentials is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.


please help on this..It swallow my whole day

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`server.pre(restify.CORS())`

to:

`server.use(restify.CORS())`